# Batch file and ftp script works, unless used with task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, ftp, scheduled-tasks

I have written a batch file that calls an FTP script that downloads files from multiple folders from a remote server. When I execute the batch file it works perfectly. However when I schedule it with task scheduler it pulls all the files down except for those in one specific folder.

I've checked permissions, there are no issues there. The relevant parts of the batch file and FTP script are below. For the purposes of this question I've shortened both. So the question would be why does it download from the "RWSmith" directory but not the "TrimarkFoodcraft" directory when run from Task Scheduler. I know that batch files are not case sensitive but I added the extra suffixes because the files do end in .DAT instead of .dat and they were not downloading.

Script and Batch File are on Windows Server 2008 R2 and the server it is downloading from is Windows Server 2003.

Batch File:

---

```
ftp -i -s:ftpCommands.txt 0.0.0.0
```

---

FTP Script:

---

```
username
password




cd "AdamsBurch"</br>
lcd "C:\EDIScanner\DistributerEDIFiles\AdamsBurch"
mget *.dat
mdelete *.dat


cd \
cd "RWSmith"
lcd \
lcd "C:\EDIScanner\DistributerEDIFiles\RWSmith"
mget *.dat
mdelete *.dat


cd \
cd "TrimarkFoodcraft"
lcd \
lcd "C:\EDIScanner\DistributerEDIFiles\TrimarkFoodcraft"
mget *.dat
mget *.DAT
mdelete *.dat
mdelete *.DAT


close
bye
```

---

Comment: Redirect `ftp` output to a file and include the output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The FTP account might not be in the root directory. After connecting, use `pwd` to see what directory is current.

```
username
password
pwd
```

Instead of assuming the directories are off of the root, use relative references.

```
cd ..
cd "TrimarkFoodcraft"
```